# Labeling on Symbology in Table of Contents of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, table-of-contents

I have to recreate a map from one I have found on the internet as close as possible for an assignment and can anyone tell me if there is some way to change the labeling in the TofC?

I'm doing a map of Africa and the climate. I found one I like online but the climate is broken down if different labels.

For instance the online map shows under the heading of Climate: Tropical Wet, Tropical wet & Dry, Arid, Semiarid... but the map layer in AcMap is showing Equatorial, Intrazonal, Subequatoral and so on.

I don't know how to add my screen shot here sorry. But what I wanted to do was leave the layer name the same: Climate but to change the sub names under Climate to match the map that I had found online. I can change the colors so they are almost alike but need to have the sub name headings the same

Comment: Can you include a picture of what you are trying to achieve, please?

Comment: I think you are referring to how the layer is symbolized in the TOC (by unique categories), not feature labels in the actual map.  Can you clarify this?  If it is about the layer symbology it is all about the data.  Make sure the data is representing what it should represent.  You can always rename or edit tabular attributes if they are not defined correctly, but you should not reclassify attributes if the data does not geographically represent the new classification.

Comment: simple. for screenshat create an image save on your computer. Edit your post and clic on 6th icon  in toolbar top of textarea

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to change what the layer name is displaying within the table of contents, right click on the layer you want to rename and go to the properties (as David has shown in his answer). From there, choose General and change the 'Layer Name' to what you'd like to see displayed in your TOC:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think you are right MaryBeth.You read the question more carefully than I did!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you certainly can change the labelling. Right click on your layer

[image]

Choose Properties at the bottom and then you have a few tabs to choose from. On the "Labels" tab you can specify which field to use for your labels. Here mine is called "Name" You will have to change the values in the choosen field in the layers attribute table if they are not as you want them.

[image]

To edit the attribute table choose "Open Attribute Table" when you right click on your layer. Then choose "Start Editing" on the editing toolbar and edit the table field to the names you would like. Stop editing and save your edits. Now the labels will change to those you have entered.